# Habanero leaves browning and dropping

Tags: diseases, leaves, peppers, damage, habaneros

I have had the pepper in question for over a year now, it was growing really well, flowered and started ripening fruits, however now it seems to be dropping all of the leaves. They first turn soft and start curling and then just drop from the plant. I am not sure what the problem could be, it seems to be afflicting a different nearby habanero as well, but not to the same extent. [image: leaf damage]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks vaguely fungal/blight-ish. There are many specific ones to sort through. I guess some folks do get multiple years for peppers, but generally speaking younger plants have more vigor than older ones that have already fruited.